# 3/8 MIP doesn't seem to fit 3/8 FIP brass gas inlet for RV furnace

Tags: natural-gas

I have this Suburban RV furnace that's brand new and didn't come with an inlet nipple to fit my 3/8 flare gas line fitting.

When I attempt to thread the 3/8MIP adapter into the brass elbow, it almost seems to fit, but not close, in fact, if I flip the adapter around so the male flare end goes into the elbow it threads nicely but very loose, however looking into the elbow there's no mating surface to provide a firm metal to metal seal. I tried using gas PTFE tape to test, but it leaks gas like crazy. any suggestions?  I've tried heating the elbow maybe not hot enough.  but it just doesn't want to catch the female threads..

I tried a 1/4 MIP and it's too small. The only size that seems to fit perfectly is the 3/8 flare side, but there's just not enough threads on the flare side, even with three or more wraps of gas tape to seal it, and seating it all the way in doesn't help either.

The 3/8 MIP union (steel) in photo doesn't seem to have enough taper to fit in the brass elbow. I've tried a brass 3/8 MIP and same problem. It doesn't want to grab the first thread.

[image: knuckle and 3/8mip to flare]

[image: looking to the knuckle]

Comment: **Best guess is that:** If the threads don't fit they are the wrong threads/size for this fitting. So 3/8 MIP does not fit because it's not, in fact, 3/8 FIP. Might be 1/4 FIP - might be something oddball.

Answer (score 1):

The photo pretty clearly shows damaged/malformed threads inside the brass L.
It should have full threads all the way to the opening.
I suggest you remove it and use a new one.
I would question whether that unit is "new".

Answer (score 0):

You should contact [Airxcel](https://www.airxcel.com/about-airxcel/contact-us). They sell these units and should be able to help. If you have a 1/2" fitting or pipe nipple I would try it.

Comment: i cannot get airxcel to call me back or respond to email.

Comment: If you go to airxcel.com, go to the bottom of the page and click on suburban, then service/support a page will come up where you can enter a zip code and they will provide a service center within your location. You can call them and ask for the fitting needed and other pertinent information.